# In prestashop how to use header and footer in custom php page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to display php pages into Prestahop body part. How can i include header and footer into my php file. Is it possible to use external page in prestashop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following to your PHP file;

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

ControllerFactory::getController('YourController')->run();

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');
?>
```